# React-spring error in Nextjs app when use back button

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-spring

Getting an error in nextjs app when using the "back button" from a page that is using react-spring.

```
ERROR:
TypeError · Cannot destructure property 'children' of 't' as it is undefined.
```

Where it happpens:

```
const SpringContext = _ref => {
  let {
    children  <---- HERE
  } = _ref,
      props = _objectWithoutPropertiesLoose(_ref, _excluded$3);
```

steps:

1. Page 1 - good, regular page with no animation
2. Page 2 - good, page has react-sprint page
3. hit back button
4. Error page with error

This is only happening on the Nextjs app I have.

Any ideas?

Here is the code where react-spring is being used. Note: I am NOT using SpringContext. It seems to be happening on the "unmount"

```
  return (
    <div className={styles.animationContainer}>
      <Transition
        native
        unique
        items={currentQuestionFlow.id || 'completed'}
        onFrame={() => window.scroll(0, 0)}
        from={{opacity: 0, transform: `translate3d(${animation.from}, 0 ,0)`}}
        enter={{opacity: 1, transform: `translate3d(${animation.enter}, 0, 0)`}}
        leave={{opacity: 0, transform: `translate3(${animation.leave}, 0, 0)`}}
      >
        {transStyles => (
          <animated.div style={{...transStyles}}>
            <Questions question={label} />
            <UIDisplay DATA={DATA} />
          </animated.div>
        )}
      </Transition>
    </div>
```

UGGGG: This might be related to me using "preact" in my production build. I removed 'preact' from my next config, so it would use react/react-dom, and the error is gone. This is an issue as preact created a smaller bundle size.

Comment: can you share the entire `SprintContext` and how it's used as well, ex. `App`?

Comment: see edited post. I am not using "SpringContext".

Comment: ok, thanks the detail. Most likely `_ref` component dismount earlier because you hit back. But you already mentioned the `preact` so maybe `preact` doesn't take care of the memory leak due to `back` button.

Comment: I updated preact and I think they fixed something. I was two minor versions behind. But updated, and no more error.